# Por que este código em C é vulnerável?

Tags: c, segurança, revisão-de-código

Tenho feito alguns exercícios de análise de código e me deparei com um caso interessante. O exercício apresenta um código em C com uma função e pergunta a qual tipo de ataque esse código é vulnerável. Não consegui identificar nada além da função gets (que pode ser explorada para ataques de buffer overflow). Existe algum outro trecho desse código que contenha alguma vulnerabilidade?

```
int crack_code()
{ 
    char code[10];
    int val=999, i;
    
    printf("Enter code: "); 
    gets(code);
    
    for (i=0; i<10; i+=2)
    {
        val = (val & code[i]) | code[i+1];
        val &= val >> code[i];
    } 
    
    if (val == 101)
    {
        return 0;
    } else
    {
        return 1;
    }
} 

void main()
{
    if (crack_code())
    {
        printf("Crack the secret code!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Now you know the secret!\n");
    }
}
```

Agradeço demais quem puder contribuir!

Comment: De cara você está utilizando a função `gets` para a leitura de uma string presumindo que tenha até 9 caracteres mas se você informar uma string de 50 caracteres a função aceitará e simplesmente destruirá o conteúdo de memória que existe após o `char code[10];`.

Comment: Basicamente é só o `gets()` mesmo. Depois há consequências por causa do uso dele.